# MySQL 5.6 Upgrade - Incorrect definition of table mysql.proc

Tags: linux, mysql, mysql5

After upgrading MySQL to version 5.6.10 from version 5.5 I'm getting the following errors when starting MySQL server:

```
2013-03-19 05:32:38 2666 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '5.6.10'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2013-03-19 05:43:27 2666 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.proc: expected column 'comment' at position 15 to have type text, found type char(64).
```

I checked out the mysql.proc table and the comment field is set to TEXT. I ran mysql_upgrade after the upgrade. I tried running it again with --force after seeing that error, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961022/mysql-5-5-9-and-mysql-proc-error) links to a bug report that mentions:

```
"start the server with the --skip-grant-tables option to cause it to skip the normal grant table checks, then run mysql_upgrade. ... Then stop the server and restart it normally."
```

reference URL from the bug report was: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/news-5-5-7.html